# Migration needed to Workplace?

Tags: discussion, migration

[More comfortable working on the backend, often referred for role on the front end](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/185589/3965) was deemed on topic by Yannis, but subsequently closed.  My own answer was not really programmer specific, but that was partially because as a programmer I understand the degree of overlap between front end and back end programmers, and I'm not sure a non-programmer could take that into account with their answer.  At any rate, it's a decent question that deserves to be open on one site or the other.  Can we settle once and for all where it belongs?

Comment: I think people see certain keywords like "interview" or "career" and immediately vote to close since the FAQ says "career advice is off-topic". Career advice is not the same as career development though, and I'd call that question a career-development question that is best answered by a programmer. I voted to reopen, but have no idea if it will get the other reopen votes it needs.

Comment: @Rachel Let's not be too quick to accuse others of carelessness, the question is borderline. Hopefully this discussion will help clarify things and we'll reach consensus.

Comment: I'll admit I was a bit quick on voting to close the question.  I have voted to reopen as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am not sure that this is a situation that can be settled authoritatively or not.  It is clearly a contreversial subject as it has been closed, reopened, and then closed again by the community.

Even after Yannis expressed his opinion on the question and cleared the previous close votes, it still received 5 more votes to close it.  As of right now there are 2 more reopen votes on it.

What this means is that there is no community consensus on this this question and the moderator already stepped in and took the action that he felt was necessary.  Typically when we reopen something we felt was closed in error, we do not do so a second time unless it was edited substantially.  This falls in the hands of the community now to figure out if these types of questions should be accepted or not.

In my opinion Yannis was correct here.  This qualifies as a Programmer Specific Business Concern as defined by the FAQ.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, the original poster seems to be gone (anon'ed).  As such, one will not be able to further clarify and rework the question to the intent the original poster had.

As it stands, it wavers between 'how not to get pigeon holed' career advice for programmers with implications of front and back end development, a general 'how not to get pigeon holed' workplace question.

Failing having the original poster come back and rework it, I believe the best course would be for someone to overhaul the question to one that is certainly not off topic for P.SE, reopen it here and not try to move it to workplace.

If it isn't possible to rework it for P.SE, then rework it for workplace so that it doesn't depend on programming knowledge and then see about migrating it over.  At that point, if it still fails a migration, it probably should remain closed.